# "Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'" при запросе к mySql

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, pymysql

Python 3.8 использую библиотеку pyMySql
Есть таблица в БД с двумя столбцами- id, name. Код должен добавлять введеное пользователем значение(test) в столбец id.

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', password = 'root', db = 'date_of_users')
cursor = connection.cursor()

test = int(input(': '))

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `dateUser` (`id`) VALUES (test)")

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dateUser")

connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO dateUser (id) VALUES ({test})")
```

Comment: Так же понадобилось установить - $ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]. Сам еще не разобрался зачем, но вдруг кто то еще столкнется с этой проблемой.